# Use CharField as a string

Tags: python, json, django, web

I want to create a model where I just put in two fields and the rest is generated with API requests, the generation I've got but I can't get the CharField in a usable string format.
So on field is:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='default')
```

And I want to run it through:

```
name = self.name.replace(' ', '+')
movieData = (json.loads(str(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + name + '&y=&plot=short&r=json').read(),'utf-8')))
movieYear = movieData.get('Year')
```

Saving movieYear as a field.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong with this.

Comment: I can use name in the context I did the second part as it is a CharField variable, not a string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that comment. Please post the full context of this code, and the whole error message.

Comment: I'm not really trying to get round an error I just want to convert a CharField into a string, manipulate it and store that as a separate CharField, thanks by the way.

Comment: A CharField *is* a string. There is no conversion to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a custom `save` will help you accomplish what you are looking to do. Here's an example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='default')
    movieData = models.JSONField(blank=True)
    movieYear = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={}&y=&plot=short&r=json'.format(self.name.replace(' ', '+'))
        data = json.loads(str(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(),'utf-8'))
        self.movieData = data 
        self.movieYear = data['Year']
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will let you make a request to a URL crafted from the `self.name` attribute (replacing spaces with `+`), then store the response in the fields you wanted.

If you use this solution, you will want to take care to include some kind of error handling - what happens if an invalid name is supplied? Or the returned data doesn't have a `Year` key for some reason? Or maybe the API is just down for a few minutes, so your valid request receives no response?

This will also make a request to that API on every save, which may have consequences for the speed of your application. You can force logic in a custom `save` to execute only when creating a new instance by using `if self.pk is None`.

Comment: The concept seems solid but when I do this I gives this error: `ValueError: Cannot quote parameter value <psycopg2._json.Json object at 0x0382D090> of type <class 'psycopg2._json.Json'>`

Comment: Try print the `data` attribute and its type before setting `self.movieData`. Make sure you're getting valid JSON there.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but how do I print it? print() dosn't do anything. When I run `import json
import urllib2
name = 'Hot Fuzz'
url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={}&y=&plot=short&r=json'.format(name.replace(' ', '+'))
data = json.loads(str(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()))` through a python 2 compiler it works.

Comment: If you have your project running with `manage.py runserver`, your `print` statements will print out to the terminal/shell/whatever window where you ran that command (and where you can see the HTTP requests that your project is making). `print(data)` (or `print data` in python2) should print something to that window when you save an instance of your model, if you include it in the save method.

Comment: I set the name to 'Hot Fuzz' and this got printed:`{u'Plot': u'Exceptional London cop Nicholas Angel is involuntarily transferred to a quaint English village and paired with a witless new partner. While on the beat, Nicholas suspects a sinister conspiracy is afoot with the residents.', u'Rated': u'R', u'Response':
u'True', u'Language': u'English', u'Title': u'Hot Fuzz', u'Country': u'UK, France, USA', u'Writer': u'Edgar Wright, Simon Pegg', u'Metascore': u'81', u'imdbRating': u'7.9', u'Director': u'Edgar Wright', u'Released': u'20 Apr 2007'
`...

Comment: Looks valid to me, try changing `JSONField` to a `TextField` and see if the error persists. If it does, the issue is that the json is failing validation when being saved somehow. Otherwise I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ok so I messed around a bit and I'm not sure why but it works now here's the code: `movieYear = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={}&y=&plot=short&r=json'.format(self.name.replace(' ', '+'))
        data = json.loads(str(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()))
        self.movieYear = data['Year']
        super(MovieAndBook, self).save(*args, **kwargs) ` It still won't migrate but it still works.

Comment: So then I copied the code into a new project and now it works and migrates, I don't know why but I think I'll just accept it.

Comment: `JSONField` can be finicky sometimes. You can always use `json.loads`/`json.dumps` to work with your saved text as a JSON object later.

Comment: Just glad it worked in the end, thanks by the way I wouldn't of found the solution with out you help!